# Read multiple files in Node js and send JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have multiple files that contains data with time stamps, so I want to read these files in order (and line by line), but I found most of the Node packages use asynchronous method to read files, how can I read each line in order and store all the data in to one string before sending it?

I want to do something like:

```
    function callbackReadFilesAndSend(res, req){
      var data = ""
      for(int i=0; i<numOfFiles;i++){
     //read lines from files
          data+=...//data from Files[i]
     }
   res.send(data)

}
```

But I think synchronous methods are bad to use in practice.

Thank you.

Comment: Synchronous is only bad if you mix them with asynchronous operation: http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony

Comment: In this case, if the file data that I'm sending is not too big, can I use readFileSync in a for loop before send it from the server?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Although you probably don't want to use `data+=` to combine all the files together

Comment: Thank you I'll try tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to execute set of known tasks in sequence in node.js you can use something like `async.series(tasks[, callback])`.

> Run the functions in the tasks collection in series, each one running once the previous function has completed.

In other to use async module you must do:

```
npm install async
```

and require it in your code:

```
const async = require('async');
```

And for this specific purpose (reading the file content), you can use node.js fs synchronous functions like `fs.readFileSync(path[, options])`.

Answer (score 0):

fs.readFileSync is a sync method for reading files. 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options